# Clickable Jquery Div returns "undefined" if you click directly on text

Tags: jquery, html, undefined, clickable

Thanks in advance for any help. I am using the following code to make an entire li "Clickable". **The problem is, if you click on any of the actual text other than the link itself (red, blue & green stats), it returns "undefined".  See live link here: `http://174.122.31.60/.`**

```
$(".available-properties li").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
 return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
$(".available-properties li").click
```

to this:

```
$(".available-properties > li").click
```

This way you only select the child LI of the available-properties UL element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(".available-properties li").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).parent().parent().find("a").attr("href");
 return false;
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xGZNS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work. With > the click function will work only on the parent and not the li in the child ul.

```
$(".available-properties > li").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a race condition if you don't filter out the 'a':

```
    $('.available-properties li').click(
        function(e) {
            if(!($(e.target).is('a'))) {
                window.location = $(this).children("a:first").attr("href");
            }
        }
    );
```